FastAPI 422 Unprocessable Entity error with JSON request from Thunkable
I'm working on a FastAPI server that receives an image URL from a JSON request and processes it. When I send the request using Thunkable and ngrok, I keep getting a 422 Unprocessable Entity error, and I can't figure out why.
Here's the setup of my FastAPI server:
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
import requests
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

SAVE_PATH = Path("uploaded_images/")
SAVE_PATH.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)


class ImageData(BaseModel):
    image_url: str 

def process_image(file_path: str):
    print(f"Processing image at {file_path}")


@app.post("/upload-image/")
async def upload_image(data: ImageData):

    image_path = data.image_url
    print(image_path)

    return {"status": "success", "image_url": image_path}

Here’s the JSON payload I’m sending from Thunkable:
{
    "image_url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dbamintid/image/upload/v1730294747/d09dfe8828ae73e48917b1c8925af291.jpg"
}

The JSON payload is verified to be like needed through ngrok inspect.
The same request works perfectly in google
header Content-Type is set toapplication/json

A 422 response means you aren't formatting the content appropriately in some way. The server is receiving the content and detects what it is, but thinks there's an error somewhere.

The body of the 422 error will also tell you what field is missing or failed validation.
